# How to use one keyboard/mouse on two PCs?

Tags: wireless-mouse

I often work from home, and would like to bring my PC laptop home and use the same wireless keyboard/mouse that I use on my home PC.

I have started out using two different keyboards/mouses, but that's a hassle.

Switched to moving the USB receiver back and forth between home PC and laptop, but that seems unsustainable because the USB receiver isn't built for switching back and forth like that.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What research have you done? :)

Comment: Couldn't you just use a simple KVM switch? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the technology used by the manufacturer but, theoretically, it may be possible to simply buy a second keyboard/mouse of the same brand/type and use that second receiver in the laptop with the devices you have already.

*Caveats*

- Bluetooth keyboards/mice generally only support one device at a time (i.e. you would still likely need to "connect" the mouse in software when switching).
- Some wireless keyboards/mice have their own methods of identifying individual devices, even if not Bluetooth. Thus, there is a small chance two devices may not work without a particular, specific receiver (but this depends greatly on the device).
- Keyboards/mice from the same manufacturer may or may not be compatible with previous generations of the same series/type (but again, this relies greatly on the device).

The other option, as mentioned by acejavelin in the comments, is to possibly use a [KVM switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) at home (which you would connect and disconnect the laptop to, rather than the receiver itself).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this:

https://symless.com/synergy

Synergy allows you to share 1 mouse and keyboard between multiple computers.

EDIT:

However, it is not free. It costs $29

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [how to recommend software in answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers), particularly the bits in **bold**; then edit your answer to follow the guidelines there. Thanks!